# Принадлежит ли точка сферическому треугольнику

Tags: математика

Есть триангулированная сфера , есть сферические координаты вершин треугольников , необходимо определить принадлежит ли точка треугольнику,то есть каждая точки задается на поверхности сферы в виде двух координат отклонения от начальной точки,360 градусов по экватору и 180 по меридиану.В целом задача : есть кривая на поверхности сферы,мы разбиваем ее на точки и пытаемся установить к какому треугольнику принадлежит точка,есть вершины треугольника и его центр, вершины(0,90;354.375,78.75;5.625,78.75) и его центр(0,82.5). Возможно кто-нибудь знает метод или может подсказать направление.

Comment: Что вы пытались сделать чтобы решить проблему? Покажите код.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://masters.donntu.org/2014/fknt/nepochataya/diss/index.htm#p43), не уверен, что спасет, но... может, на что намекнет...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175362/test-to-know-if-a-vector-is-inside-a-spherical-triangle

Comment: Вы не до конца поставили задачу: полярные координаты точек - где относительно центра находится центр изучаемой сферы? Или Вы имели ввиду координаты на сфере? Тогда это не полярные координаты. Уточните пожалуйста.

Comment: Полярные это не три луча: полярные это (r, \phi, z), сферические это (r, \phi, \psi). И это совсем разные координаты. Кроме того есть еще координаты на сфере. Никаких примеров нет при этом. Надо было дать хотя бы три точки треугольника и точку в виде буквенных координат

Comment: Тогда надо перебрасывать коорд-ы из сфер. в евклидов. и пересчитывать по способу [выше](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175362/test-to-know-if-a-vector-is-inside-a-spherical-triangle). Либо, что-то другое. В общем, вопрос требует уточнения я считаю.

Comment: да, прошу прощения за неточность, координаты действительно сферические, то есть каждая точки задается на поверхности сферы в виде двух координат отклонения от начальной точки,360 градусов по экватору и 180 по меридиану.В целом задача : есть кривая на поверхности сферы,мы разбиваем ее на точки и пытаемся установить к какому треугольнику принадлежит точка,есть вершины треугольника и его центр, вершины(0,90;354.375,78.75;5.625,78.75) и его центр(0,82.5).

Comment: @AliaksandrNazarau пожалуйста отредактируйте вопрос и включите в него это и другие уточнения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Принадлежность к тому или иному треугольнику была установлена путем нахождение расстояния между точкой и центрами всех треугольников далее выбиралось наименьшее.
Вероятно есть способ сделать это аналитически путем триангулирования поверхности  сферы и последующей проверки на принадлежность точки плоскости.